# Registerd Trademark symbol causing "Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'xyz'" error

Tags: python, sql-server, unicode, freetds

A python script is executing this query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    dbo.table_x
WHERE
    field_1 = 'xyz®'
```

When run from a Windows machine this python script works. When run from a Linux machine it fails. The database is SQL Server. On the Linux machine the driver is FreeTDS while on the Windows machine(s) the native driver is used.

The error message is

> Unclosed quotation mark after the character string **'xyz'**

The usual explanation for this problem is a wayward apostrophe in a substitution value of variable used to generate the SQL but that clearly isn't the culprit here.

Comment: It might be a character encoding issue. If the Windows file is not saved in UTF-8 then the (R) will be 0xAE, which the runtimes on Linux might be interpreting as the start of a UTF-8 group and possibly consume the apostrophe in that (although in reality that's not a valid continuation). Can you try saving the script in UTF-8 to run on Linux? Does it look OK in text editors on Linux that might also assume UTF-8?

Comment: It does appear correct when viewed in an editor. I will hex dump the python script and look at how it is representing that character.

Comment: The character looks correct in vi and when cat'ed to the screen. The hex representation of the character is c2 ae.

Comment: OK, so that's UTF-8 then already. Sorry! Must be something else then.

Comment: I checked and that is the correct Unicode representation for the 'registered' symbol.

Comment: Is the python version on windows and linux same?

Comment: Local, where it works: 3.3.3
On Linux: 3.4.3